# Extract application/json data through jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON on a web page. What is best way to extract this information through jQuery?

```html
<script type="application/json" id="user-metadata">
  {"username": "zee_162", "enrollment_mode": "audit", "upgrade_link": null, "user_id": 393900}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jQuery to parse the JSON, get the `text()` of the `#user-metadata` element, then `JSON.parse()` it:

```js
let json = $('#user-metadata').text().trim();
let obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="user-metadata">
  {"username": "zee_162", "enrollment_mode": "audit", "upgrade_link": null, "user_id": 393900}
</script>
```

Alternatively you can perform the same logic with plain JS. The only difference is how you target the element and retrieve its text content.

```js
let json = document.querySelector('#user-metadata').textContent.trim();
let obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script type="application/json" id="user-metadata">
  {"username": "zee_162", "enrollment_mode": "audit", "upgrade_link": null, "user_id": 393900}
</script>
```